# Prevent assignment of /dev/ttyUSB1

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, udev

When connecting a USB<->Serial device I know that I can create a symlink to e.g. `/dev/ttyUSB1` in my case.

Since I do not want to create a symlink pointing to it, I would like to directly have it assigned to `/dev/ttyUSB6` instead and prevent the system to assign anything to `/dev/ttyUSB1`.

I am afraid this cannot be done with `udev-rules`, but I am also lacking visibility of other options.

Anyone who can help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Device nodes (`ttyUSB*`) cannot be renamed; your best bet is to create symlinks with a naming scheme of your choice linking to the appropriate device nodes (e.g. `ttyMY0 -> ttyUSB2`, and `ttyMY1 -> ttyUSB6` etc according to attributes of the corresponding target nodes).

Comment: I think this is not correct: You actually can rename the ttyUSB* devices as I have read up the corresponding kernel files responsible for that. That is, you need to modify the kernel or write a custom driver for the serial devices.

As modifying the kernel nor writing a custom driver is an option on this project, there is no other solution than using udev rules.

Comment: "That is, you need to modify the kernel or write a custom driver for the serial devices" - at which point, why ask this question.

Comment: Iff I want to change the enumeration, the only way is to modify the kernel module. So e.g. change `drivers/tty/tty_io.c` by manipulating the function `check_tty_count`. I strongly believe there are more things to change in order to make it work, but this is a point to start. Anyway, this is an anti-pattern and I just provide this information in terms of completeness.

Comment: I'd love to help, but at the same time i don't have the time to research alternatives. PS. Usually questions like these get put on hold. :(